# What is the meaning of shell in $(shell uname -r)

Tags: gnu-make

I was reading  a makefile where I found this statement

```
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
```

Can anyone explain what is shell here. Command substitution is being tried here but for that only uname -r would have been sufficient. Why is shell word being used and what is its meaning?

I have already tried doing man on shell but as I expected it shows nothing. I also tried executing shell uname -r on command line. It does not work. I believe that this variable is defined in make.

Comment: I edited the tag since your question is related to the non-portable way `gmake` implements calls to external programs in order to use their output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet this line is within a `Makefile`, most likely a recursive call to `make`.

Makefile use `$(VAR)` (or `${VAR}`) for local variable or environment variable.

note the difference with bash where `$(VAR)` means "execute VAR and fetch result", thus for similar effect in Makefile anoter syntax is used

```
$(shell uname -r)
```

to sum up

- `$(shell uname -r)` will expand to result of `uname -r`
- `$(PWD)` will expand to `$PWD`'s value

---

see [GNU Makefile reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference)

Comment: This feature is a non-portable `gmake` feature that does not work with `make`. Please do not use the name `make` when talking about non-portable methods. Other `make` implementations support variables in the form `VAR :sh= uname -r` and `VAR :sh uname -r` since before `gmake` started to exist.

Comment: I was merely trying to answer OP and explain seen line wether `gmake` or `make`

Comment: I believe that it is worth to inform people when they are using features that are not working the same way in the original program. It is so easy to inform people that they are using `gmake` while they believe that thay are using `make`. Using non-portable features in `Makefiles` is the first step for a non-portable program.